# Expressing square in Scala

Tags: scala

For some reason (that escapes me), Scala `math` library does not have a `pow`-function for integers, but only for `Double`s.

I need a square function for integers and was figuring what might be the usual way to do this in Scala.

```
object TestX extends App {

  def pow2(v: Int)= v*v

  //class MyRichInt( val v: Int ) {
  //  def ² : Int = v*v      // says: "illegal character" for UTF-8 power-of-two
  //}

  println( pow2(42) )
  //println( 42² )
  println( math.pow(42,2).toInt )
}
```

I was surprised to see that the '²' character is not liked by Scala. Maybe it's taken to be a number? Usually all kinds of weird Unicode values are valid and using 42² in code would, indeed, be fancy.

Never mind. Should I shut up and just start using my own `pow2` function?

Comment: I don't think you know what power of two really means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two

Comment: So true. Rephrased the title and text accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, use your own `pow2`.  If you need higher powers, you probably won't have room in an `Int` anyway.  Consider using `BigInt.pow`:

```
scala> BigInt(40).pow(40)
res0: scala.math.BigInt = 12089258196146291747061760000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Of course, if you need not N<sup>2</sup> but 2<sup>N</sup>, just use shifts.  (`1 << k` = 2<sup>k</sup>)  These work with `BigInt` also.

Answer (score 16):

Use backticks for Unicode characters, and implicit classes (Scala 2.10) to add operation on arbitrary types:

```
implicit class PowerInt(i: Int) {
  def `²`: Int = i * i
}
```

Usage:

```
3 `²`
```

Result:

```
9
```

Comment: Great. But the ticks kind of dilute the niceness of actually using this. Good point though. :)